# Connected graph with where $G$ is planar but $\overline{G}$ isn't

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

How can I construct a graph $G$ of order $8$ such that $G$ is connected but $\overline{G}$ isn't?  Also, is it possible for me to construct it in such a way that neither $G$ nor $\overline{G}$ are planar?

Is there some sort of standard construction algorithm or a clever way I can do this? Or am I just supposed to do trial and error? I don't see a clear solution right away.

Comment: Can you be a bit more clear in what you're asking. The title is asking for a graph $G$ that is planar with a nonplanar complement, then in the body you ask for "$G$ that is connected but $\overline{G}$ isn't"

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** If $G$ is connected but has very few edges then $\bar{G}$ will have too many edges to be planar.

What is the smallest possible connected graph of order 8?

Comment: @AlexWang Try $G$ being $K_{3,3}$ with two isolated vertices. Show that $\bar{G}$ contains $K_5$ as a subgraph.

Answer (score 0):

Let the vertices of $G$ be $1,2,3,\dots,8$.  Let $1,2,$ and $3$ be isolated, and all the other vertices be adjacent to one another, so that $G$ has a subgraph isomorphic to $K_5$.

In $\overline{G}$ each of $1,2$ and $3$ is adjacent to each of $4,5,$ and $6$, so $\overline{G}$ has a subgraph isomorphic to $K_{3,3}$.

Neither $G$ nor $\overline{G}$ is planar. $\overline{G}$ is connected, but $G$ is not.  It is easy to modify this example so that both $G$ and $\overline{G}$ are connected and nonplanar.  I'll leave that to you.